# Notebook post-it style menu in html&css

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to create a menu like notebook post-it papers. Seems like this:
[image]

Basically want to place two divs side by side and make left div a page, and right div a menu. And if the height of page increased, the space between two menu elements should be expand proportionally. I have been trying for 2 days and the code is like that:

```
 <div class="specific_recipeBook_withStickers">

    <div class="specific_recipeBook">
        <div class="specific_recipeBook_spiral"></div>
        <div class="specific_recipeBook_main">

            <ul class="specific_recipeBook_list">
                <li class="specific_recipeBook_list_unit">
                    <div class="specific_recipeBook_main_lines"></div>

                    <a class="specific_resipeBook_list_unit_text" ><h4 id="specific_resipeBook_list_unit_name">Kuru Fasulye</h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi u</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="specific_recipebook_stickers">
        <div class="specific_recipeBook_sticker" id="recipeBook_stickers_1" ><a class="specific_recipeBook_stickers_text">Salata</a>  </div>
        <div class="specific_recipeBook_sticker" id="recipeBook_stickers_2" ><a class="specific_recipeBook_stickers_text">Tatlı</a></div>
        <div class="specific_recipeBook_sticker" id="recipeBook_stickers_3" ><a class="specific_recipeBook_stickers_text">Yan Yemek </a></div>
        <div class="specific_recipeBook_sticker" id="recipeBook_stickers_4" ><a class="specific_recipeBook_stickers_text">Anayemek  </a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztxhnya2/2/)

But it is not working well. What way should I use to do?

Comment: I have checked your codes..May be not possible in CSS.But we can do in javascript or jquery.First we need to measure the content height like $('container').height() ---> According to the content height apply to margin-top CSS  for first click button and second click button.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this function

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".specific_recipeBook").each(function(j,d) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        maxHeight = $(d).height();
        var ratioedHeight = maxHeight*0.08;
        console.log(maxHeight);
        document.getElementById("recipeBook_stickers_1").style.marginBottom = 3+ ratioedHeight+"px";
        document.getElementById("recipeBook_stickers_1").style.marginBottom = 3+ ratioedHeight+"px";
        document.getElementById("recipeBook_stickers_2").style.marginBottom = 3+ ratioedHeight+"px";
        document.getElementById("recipeBook_stickers_3").style.marginBottom = 3+ ratioedHeight+"px";
        document.getElementById("recipeBook_stickers_4").style.marginBottom = 3+ ratioedHeight+"px";
    });
});
```

Comment: Attention:$(document).ready(function ($) { //dont forget this ,i couldn't get it in. Hope you helpful.